# Yii GetStatus()

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

My User Model have 3 Status options (Active, Deleted, Blocked).
When seeing it in the view it shows as numbers 1, 2 or 3. What I can do to show it by the status name?

Model.php

```
const STATUS_ACTIVE = 1;
const STATUS_DELETED = 2;
const STATUS_BLOCKED = 3;
```

Controller.php

```
public function actionAdmin()
{
    $model=new Users('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['Users']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['Users'];

    $this->render('admin',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

View.php

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
    'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
    'id'=>'users-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'name',
        'status', // Show 1,2 or 3. I want to get the status name.
    ),
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new method in your User model called getStatusName that returns the status name. Here is one possible way of doing it:

```
public function getStatusName()
{
    switch($this->status)
    {
        case self::STATUS_ACTIVE:
            return 'Active';
            break;

        case self::STATUS_DELETED:
            return 'Deleted';
            break;

        case self::STATUS_BLOCKED:
            return 'Blocked';
            break;

        default:
            return 'Unknown';
            break;
    }

}
```

Then in your CGridView, do this:

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
    'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
    'id'=>'users-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'name',
        'statusName' // And let Yii do its magic OR be explicit
        array('name' => 'status', 'type' => 'text', 'value' => '$data->statusName'),
    ),
)); ?>
```

Note: if you used the short version on the column configuration, you should add statusName to your attributeLabels array

```
//model.php
public function attributeLabels(){
  return array(
    //Other labels
    'statusName' => 'status',
  )
}
```

This way you can also use the same attribute in other places, and let it behave like a normal attribute (only that it is read-only).

Comment: I usually create another method getStatusOptions() that returns an array of value=>name pairs and then have getStatusName() call getStatusOptions() and lookup the value in the returned array. That way you can use getStatusOptions() to easily populate dropdown lists in your forms.

Comment: Yeah, I was struggling to decide whether to use an array or switch in my example, that's why I wrote "one possible way." One method just seemed simpler to use as an example. I also use arrays to populate my drop down lists :)